# WPF, sibling selection like jQuery?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML code as an example in my WPF application

```
<StackPanel Height="23" Name="MSpanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="138" Margin="37,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="MTBox" Width="120" Text="0" />
    <ScrollBar Height="23" Name="MSBar" Width="18" TouchUp="SBar_TouchUp" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Height="23" Name="CSPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="138" Margin="37,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <TextBox Height="23" Name="CTBox" Width="120" Text="0" />
    <ScrollBar Height="23" Name="CSBar" Width="18" TouchUp="SBar_TouchUp" />
</StackPanel>
```

I have this function:

```
private void SBar_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    //what goes here?
    //siblings.getFirst('textbox').text += 1;
}
```

What I was hoping to do, is have 1 function that controls these "Psudo" numeric up downs in WPF. If there was some way to have a unified function that could, reference the sibling textbox, so I only have to write it once. That would be ideal.

I'm very familiar with jQuery, and XAML looks like an HTML DOM, ... Is there a way to browse the tree?

I realize there are existing Numeric Up Downs available to download. This idea I believe would be good to know for the future in other endeavors as well. Thanks.

---

The solution that worked!

```
private void SBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (e.NewValue == 0) return; //abort here, no change

    ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar)sender;
    StackPanel sp = (StackPanel)sb.Parent;
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sp.Children[0];

    int change = e.NewValue < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    sb.Value = 0; //this will invoke this function again
    tb.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(tb.Text) + change).ToString();
}
```

Comment: I would recomend creating user control, that would be like your own NumbericUpDown.
And >XAML looks like an HTML DOM .. yeah, looks. That is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each element in the visual tree has a `Parent` and [`VisualParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualparent.aspx) property - as all elements are based on [`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx) - either should give you the parent object.

In this case the parent of the `ScrollBar` is the `StackPanel`. You can then use the [`Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) property of the `StackPanel` to get the collection of child objects. You know which is the `ScrollBar` (it's the `sender`) so the other must be the `TextBox`.

Comment: Okay, how to I get the ambiguous ScrollBar that triggered the event? It didn't seem obvious.

Comment: @ohmusama - that'll be the `sender` parameter of your event handler.

Comment: I tried this: 
            `TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
            MessageBox.Show(tb.Name);` And it failed with an invalid cast exception.

Comment: @ohmusama - that's because the sender is the `ScrollBar` **not** the `TextBox` so that cast will fail.

Comment: How true, adding the completed solution above.

Comment: I've never used `VisualParent`. I've always used `Parent`. When would one want the `VisualParent` of an element?

Comment: @Gabe - I'm not sure ;) I think either would do.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
private void SBar_TouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    //siblings.getFirst('textbox').text += 1;
    var siblings = ((sender as FrameworkElement).Parent as Panel).Children;
    var textbox = siblings.OfType<TextBox>().First();
    textbox.Text = (int.Parse(textbox.Text) + 1).ToString();
}
```

but I would suspect that there are probably better ways to do what you want, like data binding or naming elements in attached properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there are many properties for both [Logical and Visual trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx).

Like [FrameworkElement.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx) or [Panel.Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx).

I don't think there is directly method to get sibling, but its not that hard to get index in list of children of parent and getting next item.